# Windows Server 2016 schedule automatic updates not working as set in Group Policy

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2016, windows-update

I have a Windows Server 2016 VPS where a web app is hosted.it works fine but when windows install updates,nothing works because,in this case CPU usage is 99% and no user can access the app

I've setup automatic updates in Group Policy this way:

- in Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/Windows Update
  I put  Enable for “Configure Automatic Updates”
- then value 4 for auto download/install and time for every Monday at 3am;not check the automatic maintenance box
- restart system

but Saturday on 11am no client can work on the web app because of automatic updates(CPU 99%) and I had to disable automatic update and everything went fine

how to fix schedule update to work as set in Group Policy?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: I put windows update service to manual start,then I installed PSWindowsUpdate

```
PowerShell Install-Module -Name PSWindowsUpdate
```

I've created a schedule task for every Thursday at 3am that runs a cmd:

```
sc config wuauserv start= demand    
PowerShell set-executionpolicy bypass
PowerShell Install-WindowsUpdate -MicrosoftUpdate -AcceptAll -AutoReboot
```

after the above command the windows update service becomes running, not to cause problems again, I did a second task, run on the same day but later at 5:30 am and which deactivates it:

```
net stop wuauserv
sc config wuauserv start= disabled
```